# Sitebricks HTML files

Tags: java, model-view-controller, guice, sitebricks

HTML files in Sitebricks need to have same name as Models and they should exist in WEB-INF or in the same directory as models. Just wondering is there a way to better organise HTML files. For example keeping them in separate folders? Currently if I do that I get an error saying *.html not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@Show` annotation to indicate the location of the template file that goes with a page class.

Comment: Thanks @ColinD, Yeah I found that on google groups. Do you know if sitebricks support session management? Page chaining seems to be only handling state within one request?

Answer (score 0):

SessionManagement relied on Guice.

You can use the @SessionScoped annotation or the configuration way

bind(Interface.class).to(Implementation.class).in(SessionScope.class)